# How do i create a class and the methods I need?

Tags: android

What i need to do is create an app which will generate a random mathmatical expression for the user to solve based on a difficulty level that they select.

eg. novice: a random operation on 2 terms
    easy: random operations on 2 or 3 terms

What I'm struggling with is creating a class to handle the creation of expressions

My Game class is as follows:

```
package w1279057.CW1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Game extends Activity {

public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "w1279057.CW1.difficulty";
public static final int DIFFICULTY_NOVICE = 0;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 1;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int DIFFICULTY_GURU = 3;

private int puzzle[];



@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int diff = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_DIFFICULTY, DIFFICULTY_NOVICE);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameview);
}


}
```

What i think i need is a class which has methods for generating a specific amount of operations randomly and then generating the random numbers for the expressions as well, once i have a valid expression i need to update a textview to display the expressions.

Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be a good approach, as you will decouple the mathematical logic from your Activity. So... my advice is to go in this way :)

Comment: How would my class look? As i said I'm having trouble creating methods.

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? The methods you will need depend on the functionality you need to implement... E.g. you could think as "one operation per method" to encapsulate the business logic in small pieces.

Comment: well i'll break it down into tasks that i need to accomlish, the first one would be to create a method which will generate expressions if novice is selected so i would need to choose a random operation and generate two random numbers between 0 and 100, then i'd need to update my text view to show this expression

Comment: If you need to implement the same operations for the different levels... you could considerate creating an inheritance and override the methods on each difficulty class properly!

Comment: so far i have 
 
    public class Arithmetic extends Game {
 
 
 
 int Opsel = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*4);
 }

how would i create a method in this class?

Comment: Are you sure you really know how OOP works? You should know how to create a method inside a class if you are coding and Android app! :S You have to write something like: public methodName(arg0, arg1) {code here} (Hope not misunderstood your comment).

Comment: I thought i knew OOP but trying things from past projects arent working, this is my first time programming Android

Comment: Ok, so I would recommed you to read some tutorials before starting with Android or you will have lots of problems. At least you should know the Java basics before starting... Classes, methods, objects, hierarchies...